# Vimeo video embed on iOS6 not working

Tags: ios, html, ios6, vimeo, video-embedding

I'm trying to embed a Vimeo link but it doesn't work on iOS6.  What's strange is that it worked fine on iOS5, but upgrading broke it.  What happens is after a user presses play, the progress indication will start and will hang there without ever playing.

I'm also using the latest embed code:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe data-videoid="<?php echo $video; ?>" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video; ?>?api=1&amp;player_id=<?php echo $video; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[Here's an example link where it doesn't work.](http://pn-staging.modernassemb.ly/partnersandnapier/work/excellus-bluecross-blueshield)

Comment: It works for me. I'm on 6.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I had CSS 3D transforms on the parent container...whoops!

Answer (score 0):

If are you using webview to load video then use following code, its work good for ios 6.

```
 NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                              <html><head>\
                              <style type=\"text/css\">\
                              body {\
                              background-color: #666666;\
                              padding:%f %f %f %f;\
                              color: blue;\
                              }\
                              </style>\
                              </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                              <iframe height=\"%f\" width=\"%f\" title=\"Vimeo Video\" class=\"vimeo\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@\" ></iframe>\
                              </body></html>",paddingTop,paddingRight,paddingBottom,paddingLeft,videoHeight,videoWidth,vimeoID];
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```